# Need help to identify part from Frigidaire/Electrolux laundry dryer?

Tags: repair, dryer, appliances

I was replacing rear bearing of my Frigidaire fex831fs4 dryer and now there is this extra black, plastic piece that I can't figure out, where it should go:

[image: Holding part in my hand]

I checked all the parts for my model on [Appliance Parts Pros Schematics](http://www.appliancepartspros.com/upper-cabinet-drum-parts-for-frigidaire-fex831fs4.html) and I can't even find a part that looks similar.

Since there is one unused screw hole on the top panel with screw marking, then I somewhat suspect it could go there, but then I am not sure of the purpose of that part:

[image]

**Is this a part from dyer? If yes, then where does it go? If it is not installed properly, then can it cause damage to the dryer (I did a short test and dryer seemed to work just fine)?**

Update#1: Additional close up pictures of the mysterious part.

[image]
[image]

Comment: A better photo of the part would be helpful maybe on a white piece of paper.

Comment: @EdBeal Uploaded two more close up pictures

Comment: Is there a screw left over to go with it? It looks to me like it could limit the movement of something that was suspended on springs. Can you see another one like it inside? Could it have been a buffer for transit from the factory - like when you undo the transit screws on a new washing machine? There are often unused holes on applicances - I guess they are for different models.

Comment: If you haven't wiped everything down well you may be able to see an outline in the dust/lint of where it was fastened.

Comment: I was thinking it could be a stop for the top cover but after reading platinum goose comment it may be a left over shipping part look at the underside of the top it may have fallen off or be a shipping part.

Comment: I am guessing here but I think it is a Tub Guide.  Nowadays if you have not taken something apart before - taking pictures during the process can help in reassembly. I tend to reinstall small parts into a sub assembly or leave it on loosey goosey, perhaps item 26 http://www.appliancepartspros.com/motor-blower-belt-parts-for-frigidaire-fex831fs4.html